# Flow Generic Function to create Generic Type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Let's say I have this generic flow type:

```
/* @flow */

type Cat<T> = {
  get:()=>T
};
```

And I want to create a function that creates a cat:

```
const makeCat:<U>(getter:()=>U)=>Cat<U> 
             = (getter) => ({get:getter});
```

Flow gives me the following error:

```
Cannot assign function to `makeCat` because `U` [1] is incompatible with `U` [2] in the return value of property `get` of the return value.
```

I've tried several different ways to define the types of the passed in 'getter', but it's always the same error.

Comment: [I managed to get a working example after making the code look more readable.](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwghsAPAFQHxQLxQN4CgpQDmEwAXFABQCUm6yuAvrrqJFALJwDWE8SAquiwViwYBABO5arSj8aGdH0SD8UXAHoNUAK4BnaACoowAPZQAlgDsAZpJMALaADc4Ei3ABGAG2gJdenDEuADGplZ6wFAAtty8COScPMqGQkQk4hKyFNjpZHmZUAxUzFqWtpISEAAmUHB6sAiIke5WhKih4ZFQIf5YsckIFDKKUADkBiFVwGMlmtrWdhJVtfVQLdaEnRFRrt460Fi9wAB0otS4QA) Couldn't explain _why_ this works and yours doesn't, though. Maybe someone who knows the type system a little better could

Comment: Thank you, that works!  If you post as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: I usually don't post answers without proper explanations, but sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I broke up the logic of it in to a few extra steps to make it more understandable. The key part of this solution is using `*` to tell flow to "fill in the blanks" whenever the `makeCat` function is being used.

```
type Cat<T> = {
  get: () => T
}

// define signature of "makeCat" function
type MakeCat<U> = (getter: () => U) => Cat<U>

// use * to infer the variable at usage
const makeCat: MakeCat<*> = getter => ({ get: getter })

// inferred as Cat<string>
const cat = makeCat(() => 'secret')

// inferred as string
const value = cat.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @kindaro, but simplified to not having to define the intermediary function type, by simply using the regular "old-school" function declaration form:

```
type Cat<T> = { get: () => T };

function makeCat<U>(getter: () => U): Cat<U> {
  return { get: getter };
}

// inferred as Cat<string>
const cat: Cat<string> = makeCat(() => 'secret');
// const cat: Cat<number> = makeCat(() => 'secret');  // Yields error

// inferred as string
const value: string = cat.get();
// const value: number = cat.get();  // Yields error
```

[Flow Try link here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwghsAPAFQHxQLxQN5QOYTABcUAFAJSbrJQC+A3AFCMBmArgHYDGwAlgPYcoAWzgBrCPCQBVVKQLBgEAE4kKVKNPIkpiWTkZQoywm2VDcCkgqXK6TWswD0TqLw4sVJgCZQ4AZ1gERH9gZXc8VEYuQVCoLgQdYNDwjkjMEXFJBFJ1DHQAcn8ILhNgAvImIxcoABIAUQAPSB565WV+ZWjY4HjEoKQONmEAIxV0LFEJKVzKfKgikrKKpkYa9092iF8AqBSI7o44gDc4ABs2CBJ9tIyE4AA6BQomGobmkuA2jq6Yo97ThcrlAhqMVHcEE9CC9GEA)